# Error=> error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: jsp

I am getting this error when I run my localhost in chrome.

**My Jsp program:**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page contentType="application/xml" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>

<c:choose>
  <c:when test='${param.event == "NewCall"}'>
        <%            
        String moderator_no1 =request.getParameter("moderator_no");
        String participant_no = request.getParameter("participant_no");
        String conference_id = request.getParameter("conference_id");
        System.out.println("New call");
        out.print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><response><conference moderator=\"true\" caller_onhold_music=\"default\" record=\"true\">"+conference_id+"</conference></response>");
        System.out.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><response><conference moderator=\"true\" caller_onhold_music=\"default\" record=\"true\">"+conference_id+"</conference></response>");
        session.setAttribute("state", "conferenceStarted");
        %>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test='${(param.event == "Conference" || param.event == "Hangup" || param.event == "Disconnect")}' >
        <%        
            out.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><response></response>");
            String session_id = request.getParameter("sid");
            out.println(session_id);
            System.out.println(session_id);
            String called_no = request.getParameter("cid");
            System.out.println(called_no);
            out.println(called_no);
            String actualtime = request.getParameter("total_call_duration");
            out.println(actualtime);
            System.out.println(actualtime);
            String start_time = request.getParameter("start_time");
            out.println(start_time);
            System.out.println(start_time);
            String end_time = request.getParameter("time");
            out.println(end_time);
            System.out.println(end_time);
        %>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

**Error Output in chrome:**

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I am able to print null in my logs folder when I gave event = conference but in chrome I am getting the above error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is ,

when `param.event == "Conference"`

First the response prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response></response>
```

then prints some other variables like ,

session_id ,called_no,actualtime etc.

So in the end the xml might look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response></response> 123456xyz
```

this will lead to `error: Extra content at the end of the document`.

*You have to decide how to tackle this issue.*